# Problems with MessageBox

Tags: c#

I have some code for a MessageBox, but I get a red line below the code and also in the beginning of the class at using System.Windows.Forms!?

Isn't it enough to add the using System.Windows.Forms to show MessageBoxes? Or could I have missed something else? Hints are preciated! Thanks!

EDIT:

The error message:
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have the appropriate library referenced for the namespace `System.Windows.Forms`?

Comment: U sure it (`System.Windows.Forms`) is referenced in your project.

Comment: Is this a Console application? Have you added a reference to System.Windows.Forms ?

Comment: Pleas post your code, what you have done. It's hard to make any suggestions what's missing if you don't post code.

Comment: What error, if any are you getting in the Error List window?

Comment: Firstly, if you're getting a red line below the code you'll also be getting an error message - start by reading that, there's a good chance it's telling you what to do already. If you don't understand the error message, at least tell us what it is and post the code you're using.

Comment: using System.Windows.Forms; is what I have in the beginning of class

Comment: It really seems like you have created a console application. Change the project type to `Windows application` in the project properties, and add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` in the project reference list.

Comment: Can't I create windows forms using a console application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`:

you can do that like this:

1. Right click on the project
2. click on "add reference"
3. in the opened window go to ".net" tab
4. look for `System.Windows.Forms` and press OK (or double click on it)

Comment: But I have using System.Windows.Forms; in the beginning of the class or how do you mean?

Comment: when you have a `using System.Windows.Forms` line, it doesn't mean that the assembly is referenced. that is why you should add a reference by right clicking the projects. after you have done that, you should have the `using` line so you won't have to write the full namespace by referring to the classes on that assembly

Comment: Look at that link for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192518/whats-the-difference-between-using-statement-and-adding-a-reference

Comment: OK, but could you be a little bit more precise, add reference to what?

Comment: Thanks! I just discovered that by myself. But I right clicked on the reference folder and looked in the .net. Could the reason for this be that a just copied the using System.Windows.Forms; from another file? I thought that would work without the need of adding a reference manually? Feedback please!

Comment: When you are creating a "Windows Forms Application" project, then the reference is created automatically. when you create another project that is not specified as windows forms, you should add the reference yourself (if you copied it from a different file then the reference is not copied too)

Answer (score 3):

There can be ambiguity between System.Windows.MessageBox and System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox

So maybe for simplicity just declare it as `System.Windows.MessageBox.Show()`

Answer (score -1):

try with this article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx

```
 const string message =
        "message";
    const string caption = "your test";
    var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                 MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    // If the no button was pressed ...
    if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        // cancel the closure of the form.
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```