# Why do I add `using` statements without adding a reference sometimes but other times I don't?

Tags: c#, .net, reference, using

I'm newer to C#, but why is it:

1. Some things need a `using`, but no reference. (i.e. When I need `Linq`, I just add `using System.Linq;`, but no reference)
2. Some things I need to add a reference, but no `using`?
3. Some things need both a `using` and a reference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between using statement and adding a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192518/whats-the-difference-between-using-statement-and-adding-a-reference)

Comment: Because different namespaces can be located in a one or more assemblies

Comment: Also because some parts of namespaces are already integrated in the Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET only uses fully qualified type names. But having to write fully qualified type names is a bother. Who would like to write `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` over and over, if one `using System.Data.SqlClient;` allows you to just write `SqlConnection`?

So the Language feature called "using" was invented, to allow the compiler to infer the fully qualified type name from just the class name. `using` means: "If I give you no fully qualified name, start trying to append the usings." Most of the cases this works perfectly. Only rarely do you get ambigious names (classes with identical names in 2+ Namespaces. Happens most often with Timers).

If you add a using without adding a reference, you already had the reference.

If you add a reference without adding a using, you use the fully qualified name. Or maybe a Namesapce you are already using, included that using too (I am rusty how usings transmit).

Comment: AH this explains it. So the majority of the time when I'm adding `using` statements, the default references most likely contain it, I'm just adding the fully qualified name shortcut.